# error when writing numpy into csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I want to save a numpy array into a CSV file. My code gives me an error:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path ='/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/Avito/input/'                          # path to testing file

sample = pd.read_csv(path + 'sampleSubmission.csv')

index = sample.ID.values - 1

test =  np.array(pd.read_csv(path + 'dataset5test.csv'))

#print new[0:10,:]

new = test[index,:]

np.savetxt(path + 'testSearchStream9.csv', new, delimiter=",")

os.system('say "Done"')
```

This is the error that I get:

```
    np.savetxt(path + 'testSearchStream9.csv', new, delimiter=",")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1061, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the form of data that you are going to save .By default it takes float as format

```
np.savetxt(path + 'testSearchStream9.csv', new, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

See section on [savetxt function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) of SciPy documentation.